# Class not found replit

Tags: java

I'm using repl.it as my IDE, just to preface things. I have a FileManager class, and I'm using it in my main class. The issue is that repl.it is giving me this error:
`Main.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
  static final FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
               ^
  symbol:   class FileManager
  location: class Main`

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, as I definitely have the class in another file.

Main class (not the full thing):

```
class Main {
  static final FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    fileManager.saveNetworksToFile(networks);
  }
}
```

FileManager class (not the full thing):

```
public class FileManager {
  public void saveNetworksToFile(ArrayList<Network> nn) {
    //Code
  }
}
```

Comment: the FileManager.java file is in the same project, I don't think that I would need to import it. I also have other classes that I am using without any issues at all. The FileManager one is the only one giving me any issues.

Comment: Did you import everything you need? It works fine for me just fine:
https://repl.it/repls/PlayfulFoolishSloth

Comment: I put the error above. Here is a link to the project: https://repl.it/@Toggytokyo/Java-Neural-Network

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong - the FileManager file did not have the .java extension.